# In Rspec file, shared examples gets executed at the end in the list of examples

Tags: rspec, rspec2

I have issue with execution of shared examples.The shared example always gets executed at the end in the list of examples. How to run all the examples in the order ?

I have shared example spec  which looks like

sharedExamples_spec.rb

```
shared_examples "upload jar" do |msg|
  it "shared examples group" do
    sleep(10)
    p "hello there :2 #{msg}"
  end 
end
```

And in other spec file

```
require 'sharedExamples_spec.rb'

    describe "something" do

       before(:each) do
         @spec = "something group"
       end


 it "1: does something" do
   puts "hello there:1 #{@spec}"
 end

 describe "shared example" do
   it_should_behave_like "upload jar"," shared group"
end

it "3: does something" do
  puts "hello there:3 #{@spec}"
end

end
```

Rspec Output I get is

```
something
 hello there:1 something group
  1: does something
 hello there:3 something group
  3: does something
 shared example
   it should behave like upload jar
    "hello there :2  shared group"
  shared examples group

 Finished in 1 second
  3 examples, 0 failures
```

If you see the the output,  Shared examples is executed as the last example.  Can anyone please suggest how to execute the test in the order that is written.

Comment: Your tests shouldn't depend on order. Ideally, they should be run in a random order.

Comment: I agree, but my scenario is to test series of test and validate DB in every test.  The shared example does a common operation which I am using in other test. So in brief , first test sends a http request to a service and validates the DB, second one is (shared example)  upload the the dummy data to the DB and runs a validation and the third test test is to sent different set of data to service and check the DB.  so for me the order of execution is important in this case. Is there any way I can force the rspec to run each test in sequential under "describe" ?

Comment: Your scenario goes against the idea of running tests in isolation. You shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this phenomenon has anything to do with shared examples per se. Within a given `describe` block, RSpec appears to run all `it` examples before running any nested `describe` examples, as illustrated by the following:

```
describe "order test" do
  it {puts 1}
  describe "nested describe" do
      it {puts "2"}
    end
  it {puts 3}
end
```

which produces:

```
1
.3
.2
.
```

The comments about not depending on test order notwithstanding, if you want a `describe` block to execute before an `it` at the same level, I think you'll need to put the `it` in it's own `describe` block. In your case that would look like:

```
describe "something" do

  before(:each) do
    @spec = "something group"
  end

  shared_examples "upload jar" do |msg|
    it "shared examples group" do
      p "hello there :2 #{msg}"
    end 
  end

  describe "example 1" do
    it "1: does something" do
      puts "hello there:1 #{@spec}"
    end
  end

  describe "shared example" do
    it_should_behave_like "upload jar"," shared group"
  end

  describe "example 3" do
    it "3: does something" do
      puts "hello there:3 #{@spec}"
    end
  end

end
```

which produces:

```
hello there:1 something group
."hello there :2  shared group"
.hello there:3 something group
.
```

Comment: I tried that but the shared example cannot be included within another "it".

Comment: This seems more like a workaround then a solution. There are many situations when tests isolation makes no sense and Rspec should not rely on that.